# MobX - how to comunicate between stores?

Tags: javascript, mobx

In my application i have two MobX stores - store_A for handling user information (who is currently logged, etc), and store_B for handling events for all users.
After user login, i want to display all events regarding that user.
How can i access logged user info (from store_A) from within store_B so that i can filter events correctly?
At this point i have to store loggeduserName data inside my store_b to retrive that data...
Code from my events store:

```
class ObservableEventsStore {
...
//after logIn, save userName: 
  @action setUser(userName) {
    this.givenUser = userName
  } 
...
@computed get filteredByUser() {
    let filteredByUser = this.wholeList
      .filter((event) => this.givenUser === event.user)
      // this.givenUser is what i want to get from store_A 
    return filteredByUser
  }
```

I want to get `loggedUser` data from UserStore, i have it stored there as well ...

Comment: I like the advice in the ["Defining data stores"](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/store.html)-part of the documentation. Your `ObservableEventsStore` could hold a reference to the UserStore, or just your User.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no idiomatic approach, any means to obtain a reference to the userStore is valid. I think in general you can take three approaches to achieve this:

1. construct the userStore before the EventStore and pass the reference to the EventStore in it's constuctor (or set it afterwards)
2. If the UserStores is a singleton, just import and use it
3. Use a dependency injection system like InversifyJS

Comment: thanks for swift reply :)
At the moment i figured a way around - get logged user from userStore in component, and then use it in query for eventComponent.
`eventsStore.filterEventsByUser(userStore.loggedUserName)`
But I'll definetly try yours ideas, especially 2nd one talks to me nicely :D